# How can I remove the stem on my leaking IKEA faucet?

Tags: repair, faucet

I have an IKEA LOVIKEN AA-291347-1 faucet. It leaks between the 2 handles at the connection.
I removed the screw behind, but I cannot remove the top center part.
Do you have any idea how I can open it to change the seal inside?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How old is the faucet?  Is it still under warranty?

Comment: after removing the screw it should just lift out, maybe you need to wiggle it a bit or turn it to a certain angle.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 1):

While you have removed the locating screw, there are usually 3 rubber (well nitrile or somesuch) sealing rings which are a tight fit.

So, you might have to twist and pull very hard to get them to release.

At least, that was the case when I took a similar tap apart.

Of course, lots of care needed to get it back together without damaging the new seals...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that part is factory assembled, not removable. You may want to check with the manufacturer, if there's a local 800 number. Maybe they'll give you a brand new one.